# Java Swing JMenuBar malfunctions

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenu, jmenubar

I'm working with Intellij IDEA, Java 9.0.1 and Gradle.
I'm trying to create my first swing app, I created a JMenuBar, but for some reason the resulted menu doesn't always turn up, like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Also, when it doesn't - it shows if I adjust the application's window size, then it works:

[image]

I tried looking up at [Initial Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) but I really don't understand why the issue is happening.

this is the full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Menu");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(350,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        //File category
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(file);
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        file.add(exit);

        //Edit category
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        menubar.add(help);
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
        help.add(about);

        //Exit option action listener
        class exitAction implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }
        exit.addActionListener(new exitAction());
    }
}
```

Comment: One common e rule is that components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is packed and made visible.

Comment: Thank you so much!!